# How to chain multiple RxJava's groupBy() methods such as groupBy().groupBy()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

Given input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Group the numbers by odd or even and then by less than or greater than 5.

Expected output:

```
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4], [6, 8, 10], [7, 9]]
```

The order of the output isn't restricted.

I'm now using the following approach:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .groupBy(n -> n % 2 == 0)
    .flatMap((GroupedObservable<Boolean, Integer> g) -> {
        return Observable.just(g).flatMap(ObservableUtils.<Boolean, Integer>flatGroup()).groupBy(n -> n > 5);
    })
    .subscribe((final GroupedObservable<Boolean, Integer> g) -> {
        Observable.just(g).flatMap(ObservableUtils.<Boolean, Integer>flatGroup()).forEach(n -> println(g + ": " + n));
    });
```

Note that ObservableUtils is written by me to simplify the code.

But I'm not satisfied with it because it still not short enough to simply indicate the goal only.

What I expected is like the following:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .groupBy(n -> n % 2 == 0)
    .groupBy(n -> n > 5)
    .subscribe(...);
```

For now I can only shrink it to:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .lift(new OperatorGroupByGroup(n -> n % 2 == 0))
    .lift(new OperatorGroupByGroup(n -> n > 5))
    .subscribe(...);
```

I still have to write the OperatorGroupByGroup class which is a little bit complex. Any suggestion for improving?

Answer (score 4):

Try to do it in this way.

```
Observables.range(1,10)
  .groupBy( n -> n % 2 == 0)
  .flatMap( grp -> grp.groupBy( n -> n > 5).flatMap( grp2 -> grp2.toList()))
  .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a sample for OperatorGroupByGroup that based on OperatorGroupBy:

https://github.com/yongjhih/RxJava-GroupByTest

Usage:

```
git clone https://github.com/yongjhih/RxJava-GroupByTest.git
./gradlew execute
```

But I modified testing code due to my OperatorGroupByGroup implementation:

```
    Observable.range(1, 10)
    .lift(new OperatorGroupByGroup<Integer, Boolean, Integer>(n -> n % 2 == 0))
    .lift(new OperatorGroupByGroup<GroupedObservable<Boolean, Integer>, Boolean, Integer>(n -> n > 5))
    .subscribe((final GroupedObservable<Boolean, Integer> g) -> {
        Observable.just(g).flatMap(ObservableUtils.<Boolean, Integer>flatGroup()).forEach(n -> println(g + ": " + n));
    });
```

I think somebody would do better.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions that I think are both pretty concise and elegant.

First:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .groupBy(n -> n % 2 == 0)
    .flatMap(g -> g.groupBy(n -> n > 5))
    .subscribe(...);
```

Which is almost as good as your expectation, just one additional `.flatMap()`. The only problem? You lose the first key, but I'm not sure you're using those anyway.

Second needs declaring a simple `Key` class that can hold results of both your conditions and have proper `equals()` implementation. In other words a `Pair`. Then you can do:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .groupBy(n -> new Key(n % 2 == 0, n > 5))
    .subscribe(...);
```

This has the disadvantage of being less composable, as you have both conditions in the same `.groupBy()` call instead of chained. The advantage is that you can use a combined key that holds results of both your conditions if you need them.